# Eclipse does not show WildFly in server libraries

Tags: eclipse, wildfly, wildfly-8

Why Eclipse does not show WildFly in `Build Path -> Configure Build path -> Add library -> Server Runtime`? Note that WildFly 8.0 was added in Prefereces -> Servers -> Runtimes.

Comment: do you have jboss tools installed? http://tools.jboss.org/

Comment: Of cource, it is. Do you mean it is a chance to reinstall JBT?

Comment: You need to add new server in "Servers" view and define added runtime for this new server as default. 
**Add new server:**
1) inside "Servers" view under "right click" menu select "New" Server
2) choose server type "JBoss Community", "Widlfly..."
3) Assign previously installed runtime to new server

Comment: @ctomc 's comment should be posted and accepted as an answer. worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

After you install new EE server runtime you need to add new server in servers view.

**Add new server:**

1. inside "Servers" view under "right click" menu select "New" Server
2. choose server type "JBoss Community", "Widlfly..."
3. Assign previously installed runtime to new server and finish configuration